# Regular Expression - Starting with and ending with string

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to write a regular expression to match files that starts with "AMDF" or "SB700" and does not end with ".tmp".  This will be used in Java.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `^(?:AMDF|SB700).*\.(?!tmp)[^.]+$`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] to get an idea of how to ask good questions. Questions that simply ask for an implementation aren't encouraged...

Comment: I have: ^(AMDF|SB700 ).*\.tmp  but need to do the opposite of (\.tmp). I do not know if ^(\.tmp) will work, and not sure if Java supports 'negative look-behind' to use (?<!tmp)$

Comment: `(fileName.startsWith("AMDF") || fileName.startsWith("SB700")) && !fileName.endsWith(".tmp")`? No need to use regex.

Comment: @bcsb1001  I am injecting the regex from a config file. I can not modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/opWZwU/2)

```
^(?:AMDF|SB700).*\.(?!tmp$)[^.]+$
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/ohJlSc)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "^(?:AMDF|SB700).*\\.(?!tmp$)[^.]+$";
        final String[] files = {
            "AMDF123978sudjfadfs.ext",
            "SB700afddasjfkadsfs.ext",
            "AMDE41312312089fsas.ext",
            "SB701fs98dfjasdjfsd.ext",
            "AMDF123120381203113.tmp"
        };

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

        for (String file:files) {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
            if(matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
AMDF123978sudjfadfs.ext
SB700afddasjfkadsfs.ext

AMDE41312312089fsas.ext
SB701fs98dfjasdjfsd.ext
AMDF123120381203113.tmp
```

#### Output

Below shows only matches.

```
AMDF123978sudjfadfs.ext
SB700afddasjfkadsfs.ext
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:AMDF|SB700)` Match either `AMDF` or `SB700` literally
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\.` Match a literal dot `.` character
- `(?!tmp$)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match `tmp` literally (asserting the end of the line afterwards so as not to match `.tmpx` where `x` can be anything)
- `[^.]+` Match any character except `.` one or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: @martinezjosei it really is. It does a good job of explaining tokens. It doesn't check against Java, however, so if you're looking to validate it in terms of Java you should use something like [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) instead

Comment: This works the best. How do I add the Pattern.MULTILINE = (?m) in the expression itself?

Comment: @martinezjosei you'd simply add any flags to the start of the pattern such that `(?m)` precedes the pattern: https://ideone.com/jTHSpL

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to try a regex using a negative lookahead to assert that the file name does not end on `.tmp` and use an anchor `^` to make sure that the file name starts with `AMDF` or `SB700` like:

[`^(?!.*\.tmp$)(?:AMDF|SB700)\w*\.\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/zqsIks/2)

**Explanation**

- The beginning of the string `^`
- A negative lookahead `(?!`
- To assert that the string ends with .tmp `.*\.tmp$`
- A non capturing group which matches AMDF or SB700 `(?:AMDF|SB700)`
- Match a word character zero or more times `\w*`
- Match a dot `\.`
- Match a word character one or more times `\w+`
- The end of the string `$`

In Java it would look like:

`^(?!.*\\.tmp$)(?:AMDF|SB700)\\w*\\.\\w+$`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MJMY37939)

Comment: @martinezjosei Yes it will. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: After some more robust test, it failed by use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that works:

^(SB700|AMDF).*(?!\.tmp).{4}$